# How/Can i flip/rotate a page 90° in Scribus

Tags: rotate, scribus

i am currently using Scribus to make a scientific poster. I wanted to design it horizontally (so the long sides are North an South and the short ones E&W).
I couldnt find anything about it in www and the manuals. 
I only want to rotate the page/the whole object not just one single item. In the view menu theres no option for that. 
Anyone who can help me?
Or can i make two pages/wouuld that be easier? (like for a book, described in this guide: http://www.depot1.dk/images/Scribus_Guide_UK.pdf)?
Thanks already in advance,
Lirie

Answer (score 1):

You should not rotate full pages.

But you can create a "rotated" page by adding a landscape page:

- page > insert
- orientation : lanscape

You can then layout your landscape page without rotating!

This is the answer for your question... But i wonder, if you are not looking for creating a full landscape document.

In that case, just create a new document and pick the "landscape" orientation.

Comment: +1 Also you can edit the properties of an existing page by Page --> Manage page properties.

Comment: Thank you people! I was totally overwhelmed that i didnt see the option for landscape, i always just thought about rotating it...