# Rotate pdf pages using Scribus

Tags: pdf, rotate, scribus

Using Ubuntu 22.04LTS on various machines (Desktop / Laptop).

I use Scribus to do basic editing in pdf files (eg inserting signature, or text as text boxes).

When I'm sent a pdf that's malrotated, I need to orient it properly before editing.

I found this [How/Can i flip/rotate a page 90° in Scribus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924918/how-can-i-flip-rotate-a-page-90-in-scribus/924924#924924) but it doesn't answer what I want to do.

There is a rotate option in Scribus, but it's manual - so you have to drag the window round or use the arrow keys until it's correct. But dragging exactly 90 degrees is timeconsuming and difficult. I have found that by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and arrow-keys, it rotates in 10 degree increments which makes it precise (ie 9 taps for the 90 degrees), but it's still much slower than a 90-degree selection.

Is there a quick / simple way to rotate pdf pages exactly 90 degrees?

Many thanks.